# How make longer lifetime of battery?

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, battery

Please help to setup power perfomance on the laptop. Before Ubuntu 14.04 LTS use Win7 and work time was about 4 hours after 1,5-2 hours. Tried everything install Bumblebee, TLP.

Lenovo e430 Intel i5-3210m, Intel Ivy Bridge/GeForce GT630M

Answer (score 0):

It may not be particular to windows or linux, and even if it is, it may be a matter of configuring its power saving features under system settings in Ubuntu.  You can even work with your desktop colors so that you can tolerate using lower screen brightness.

I just explained this on another question but yours is slightly different.  Laptop battery life can become unpredictable when it is on the verge of going completely bad. Occasionally, and by that I mean one time out of ten, I can wake up a purportedly bad battery by repeatedly running down its 2-4 hour life span and putting it on charge until it thinks it is full, and after a few such cycles it wakes up and charges very long and then runs for five hours or something still more incredible.

If you are considering replacing the battery, I've found it for $24 on amazon:
[http://www.amazon.com/compatible-Extended-Capacity-Replacement-Battery/dp/B00GDPOZWA/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1419061910&sr=8-1&keywords=lenovo+e430+battery&pebp=1419061924417](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GDPOZWA)